# How to add events to buttons of GridView in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I have a search page in asp.net, user searches a book and results are listed in a gridview. I added a button to the right of each gridview result column, and i want to add an event to these buttons, for example, when user clicks the button, that book is loaned. Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SearchResults.aspx.cs"  Inherits="Pages_SearchResults" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
    </div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ISBN" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ISBN" HeaderText="ISBN" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="ISBN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AuthorName" HeaderText="Author Name" 
            SortExpression="AuthorName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AuthorlName" HeaderText="Author Last Name" 
            SortExpression="AuthorlName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemType" HeaderText="Item Type" 
            SortExpression="ItemType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PublishYear" HeaderText="Publish Year" 
            SortExpression="PublishYear" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="LoanItem" Text="Loan Item" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Items] WHERE ([Title] LIKE '%' + @Title + '%')">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="tSearchBox" Name="Title" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the .cs file of this SearchResults page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Pages_SearchResults : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I added the buttons like the following: Clicked on BUttonField

[image]

My question is, how can i add an event to those "Loan Item" buttons? I read this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498195.aspx but it does not really tell how the event handler is added. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do, and what I think your example link is doing, is adding the RowCommand event to the GridView.

When you click a button, the RowCommand event will be fired, and the CommandName and CommandArgument (which would be an ID that identifies the row/record associated with the button that was clicked) for the button are passed to the event handler.

To create the handler, see my comment below, or do it manually. In your grid:

`OnRowCommand="Grid_RowCommand"`

And in your codebehind:

```
protected void Grid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Convention would dictate that the name of the handler should be [ControlID]_[EventName] so in my example, the ID of my grid is simply `Grid`

Comment: Yes, i am trying to do that, but for example to add an event to an ordinary button, i just double click on it and a function is created for me and then i write the code to the function. But here when i double click on gridview or its buttons, only GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged function is created for me and the code inside does not work.

Comment: If you select your Grid in design view and look at the Properties window, you should see a little lightning bolt at the top (You may need to select and deselect the grid a few times, it can be a bit odd). Click the lightning bolt and you should see a list of all the possible events. Double click in the blank space to the right of the RowCommand event to auto-create a handler.

Answer (score 3):

if you add the button through the wizard `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` should be firing every time you click on a row button. So all you need to do is figure out the selected row and act accordingly.

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
```

be warned that there can be more than one selected rows if you haven;t specified otherwise.

Comment: Actually, i wanted to see whether it is firing every time i click on a button and written Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); inside it to see whether anything will happen, but it did not redirect

Comment: how did you add the button? it's alway easier for me to add a select button from the gridview wizard and just change the name to whatever i need. let me know if you need help adding it

Comment: Thanks, i added it from "Edit columns" properties of the gridview, is there any other way to add it?

Comment: there are more ways of doing it but i think that's the one that requires less effort. also, if you don't use the default buttons, you are not going to be able to figure out the selectedrowindex without using any client code to alert the server of the row clicked...

Comment: Actually, i do not know, this is the first time i am trying to do such a thing. I edited the question to show how i added the buttons, can you have a look at it and give me an advise about how to add buttons to each result row?

Comment: I found out how to do, Jason P's advise worked. Thank for your help too!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
  <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="LoanItem" Text="Loan Item" />
```

to

```
     <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Buttonid" runat="server" CommandName="LoanItem" Text="Loan Item" OnClick="Button_click_event"></asp:Button>    
        </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

in Code Behind

```
Private void Button_click_event(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
// Click Event of Button
}
```

Comment: It sasy Button is undefined