# Gridview Select Index Change Returning Null Value

Tags: .net, vb.net

Select Index Row returning null but if I remove *AutoGenerateColumns="False"* property then it works fine but I cant use AutoGenerateColumns becuase I want textboxes within gridview.

**Gridiview Code**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"   class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                 <Columns>
                       <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("ID") %>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField >

                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Case">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("Case") %>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                         </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>
```

**Select Index Change Method**

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text.ToString()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself, adding the updated code for others

```
 <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="ID">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>  
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have added Label field and retrieve the value using field Control

```
    Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

            Dim TestCase As String = DirectCast(GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("Label1"), Label).Text

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to have textboxes without autogenerating the columns, you should use TemplateColumns.

[Click for the official MSDN page.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx)

Second, to get the row in SelectedIndexChanged, you should select the row. Using a button in DataGrid is a good way to do it. But you should set its CommandName property to "Select".

[Here is an example to how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735569/how-to-add-events-to-buttons-of-gridview-in-asp-net)